# how can I extract columns from my json dataset?

Tags: python, ijson

my jsons looks like `{"metadata"}` ,but it always return me as `[]` empty , but I want to properly extract the keys

```
with gzip.open(gzip_file) as file:
    parser = ijson.parse(file)
    objects = ijson.items(parser, 'meta.view.columns.item')
    columns = list(objects)
```

Comment: can you share sample of your json and i can attempt

Comment: Also, there's no need for the `ijson.parse` call, pass `file` directly to `ijson.items`. Using the correct prefix should yield the objects you want.